# How to increase/decrease value with reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reduce

I am working on a temperature control app with react native. To get the value of the temperature I use redux toolkit. My problem is that my code for increasing/decreasing the initial value with the reducers doesn't work. I get the 20 as value but using handlers to dispatch(in/decreaseTemp()) doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Reducers:

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const initialStateValue = {
        value: 20
    }

    const tempSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'temp',
        initialState: initialStateValue,
        reducers: {
            increaseTemp: (state = initialStateValue) => {
               state = state + 1;
            },
            decreaseTemp: (state = initialStateValue) => {
               state = state - 1;
            }
        }
    });

    export const {increaseTemp, decreaseTemp} = tempSlice.actions;
    export default tempSlice.reducer;
```

The handlers:

```
    function increaseTempHandler() {
      dispatch(increaseTemp());
    }

    function decreaseTempHandler() {
      dispatch(decreaseTemp());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a mismatch between how you've defined your state

```js
const initialStateValue = {
  value: 20
};
```

and how you're using it:

```js
increaseTemp: (state = initialStateValue) => {
  state = state + 1;
},
```

If state is an object that has a `value` property then your reducer should be returning a new state that has the updated `value` property.

e.g.

```js
increaseTemp: (state = initialStateValue) => {
  const { value } = state;
  return { ...state, value: value+1 }
},
```

Comment: Even when you use Immer, it is not required to mutate state.